# Bootstrap button "loading" animation works at the end

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button that calls an Ajax function and show users' info in some textarea

HTML:

```
<button id="btnUsers" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-lg" onclick='navUsers.getUsers();' data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Processing Order">  Get Users   </button>
<textarea id="resultUsers" name="resultUsers" cols="100" rows="18" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var navUsers = new function (){ 
    this.getUsers = function(){
       $("#btnUsers").button('loading');
       $.ajax({ //ajax stuff, shows users in the textarea })
    };
};
```

The problem is: the button's 'loading' animation only starts **after** the Ajax stuff is finished, not before. I've tried some 'modal' bootstrap div for showing mensajes while loading users and same happens. Also I've tried the `beforesend`option in Ajax, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var navUsers = new function (){ 
    this.getUsers = function(){
       $("#btnUsers").button('loading');
       setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({ 
            //ajax stuff,
            success:function(){
            $("#btnUsers").button('reset');
          }
       })
    }, 1000);

    };
};
```